# How do I submit a Vuforia application for Facebook review as a simulator build?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am creating an iOS app that uses Unity3D, the Vuforia AR SDK, and Prime31 Social Networking Plugins.

In order to publish a screenshot to a user's Facebook timeline, my app needs the "publish_actions" permission. To use this I need to submit the app for review by Facebook, in the form of an Xcode Simulator Build.

However, Vuforia does not support simulator builds:
https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-4-compiling-and-running-vuforia-sample-app
"Note: Vuforia applications do not build or work with the Simulator."

Has anyone managed to get an iOS Vuforia-based app reviewed by Facebook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue.

Apparently the situation is impossible:

The problem here is:
- To pass the Facebook Review process you need to send them your App in one of this two available format,  1) the Apple App Store App (that is impossible to do, you can not send App Store an unfinished app), or 2) a Simulated Build (using Terminal to build the project in xcodebuild -arch i386 simulatorXX). None of this available options provided by Facebook are posible technically, so it's technically imposible to obtain the approval of the App. This is because:

1- App Store is not going to pass an App that is not working (the FB butto won't work, so App Store is not going to allow us finish the process and they will reject). so at the you can not provide an AppStore-id to the Facebook Review team.

2- As far as Facebook only receives "Simulated Builds" it would be impossible to a Vuforia Unity App to be accepted, this is because when you are using Unity + Vuforia you can not build a simulated build, is incompatible. So is impossible to fit this requirement.

Only workaround available I can think of would be to:

1- Send the app to apple store, remotely disabling the Facebook functionality.
2- Once is approved by Apple, remotely enable the Facebook functionality and sending the app - THE APP STORE ID - to Facebook Review.

Otherwise, Facebook should open another via to Vuforia-Unity developer to review their IOS apps.

This seem to be the only way for Vuforia + Unity, but I didn't check it.

Comment: The only solution I was able to reach was to work with a member of the Facebook review team directly. They provided a UDID of a test device and I was able to provide them an ad-hoc build of the app that they could test. Clearly this isn't an ideal solution for either the developer or for Facebook.